# Load multiple files containing text into MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash

I have several folders each containing four text files. I am trying to load the data from each file into a corresponding column in a MYSQL table all on the same row. I have used the LOAD DATA INFILE command on the files individually which works, but this ends up creating new entries for each text file. Is there a way to load data from multiple files and assign each file to a specific column in the table without new entries being created?

I have tried something like the following command but I don't think it exists.

LOAD DATA INFILE 'col1.txt', 'col2.txt', 'col3.txt', 'col4.txt' INTO TABLE testing (col1,col2,col3,col4);

I have thought of merging the files together into one file and separating them with commas. However, I cannot get this option to work since some of the files contain multiple lines of text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

My text files are like this name.txt which is just a first and last name on a single line text file. Address.txt which is the full address spanning 4-5 rows/lines in the text file. I also have phone.txt which is a single lined text file. Company.txt contains the company name on a single lined text file.

When I run paste -d "|" name.txt address.txt phone.txt company.txt

The output looks like:

```
Joe Smith|123 Fake St|416-555-1212|ACME INC
|Toronto, ON||
|H0H 0H0||
|Canada||
```

If I load that into my database, the address will only contain 123 Fake St on the row and then the next row below will have Toronto, ON and so on. I would like the load the entire multiple line address into the address column in my database. Any thoughts on how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing the basic issues of data loading.

You are right, you need combine the column files so that they create one file. You are much better off to use either the tab char or some other char not in the data, usually '|' will work nicely.

```
paste -d "|" 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt. 4.tx
```

should work.

What do you mean multiple lines of text. We'll need an example to fix that. Click the edit link below your post AND note the formatting options across the top. Paste in you sample problem data, select it, then click on either {} or `` to format the data with fixed width characters. Note finally that you can see what your message looks like as you type in below the input box.

EDIT : 4th file with multi-line values for 1 column.

This is very much a work in progress, as we don't know what the data looks like in reality.
Given data like

```
ACME INC
Toronto, ON
H0H 0H0
Canada

ACME INC
Toronto, ON
H0H 0H0
Canada
```

AND that each 'record' is separated by a blank line, you can pre-filter that file to create single line records that look like

ACME INC
Toronto, ON
H0H 0H0
Canada

ACME INC
Toronto, ON
H0H 0H0
Canada

with the following awk code

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"; } { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ printf "%s ", $i; };printf "\n";} ' test4.txt > text4.txt.cln
```

Modify the paste command to use file4.txt.cln
and let us know what happens.

If your data IS separated by 1 blank line, then we're good. If it is all run together, then we need some sample data. Hopefully there are exactly always N (4 or 5 or ?) lines of data per customer. That will be easy to convert. If not, then you'll have to go back to how you create file4 and come up with a way to produce the file in one of these formats.

Other SO readers, please see comments below for full story.

IHTH

Comment: @shellter

Thanks for your help. I have updated my original question with sample data to better clarify my issue.

Thanks again

Comment: @James : is this a one off problem OR it this going to be a process? If a one off, then we have to flatten out file4. If there are more surprises in your data OR you're going to do this all the time then why can't this data be all in 1 file from the start. Where are you getting it from, why isn't it all 1 file? This would be a normal data processing step, to extract all fields need in a single SQL query into 1 file. Is the data from a database?

Comment: @shellter : I admit that I am probably doing this in a very inefficient manner but what I am doing is creating a directory of local businesses so this will be a repeated process. The reason that there is multiple files is that I am getting the information off of local company websites and then using grep -o with the appropriate regex statements to grab the data I need and then put it into the separate file named after the data it contains. If you have any ideas on a better approach I could take, I would be very greatful as I have been just hacking along so far and now I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Hmm.. Well your overall process is very open to error, based just on 1 missing line of data. Paste won't know that line 3 of file1 is missing (for example) and will 'join' together the wrong lines, from than point on until the end, AND now we know you're parsing html with regular expressions (not good, and you're seeing why).  All of that aside, I'll give you some ideas about folding up file4 into 1 line records. Editing the answer.

Comment: @James, I'm going to bed. I won't be looking at this until tomorrow afternoon. I am worried about 1 more thing. The data |ACME INC
|Toronto, ON||
|H0H 0H0||
|Canada||, with all the extra '|' chars. I'm realizing now that means 'line of text'. Does each 'record' composed of 10 lines? If not, that is a problem as I describe in answer proper. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : Thank you so much for all your help. My script is now working. I can finally move forward with my site.

Comment: P.S. I cannot upvote your answer because I don't have a reputation of 15 yet. I have marked your answer as correct though.